# RaspBerrypie SIP to Pa Device, using pjsip

Tags: linux, audio, sip

i been struggling with a little RaspberryPie project (iv tried it on RaspberryPie 3 and 4)
Basically i am trying to build a SIP to Loudspeaker Converter using a Raspberry pie.

So far installing pjsip and overcomining the absent mic fault (using PulseAudio and stipulating audiodevice in the pjsip ext.conf file) has been fairly straight foward i can get my extension to register and recieve calls as well as autoanswer and send audio to the audio jack.

Currently i can get this to work by running my ext.conf file in the pjsip-apps/bin/arm folder like below

```
sudo /home/pi/pjsip/pjproject-2.11.1/pjsip-apps/bin/pjsua-armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --config-file /home/pi/200.cfg
```

My ext.conf file looks like below

```
[200]
--id sip:sip200@192.168.0.101
--registrar sip:192.168.0.101
--realm *
--username sip200
--password sip200
--auto-answer 200
--capture-dev 0
--playback-dev 0
```

I am now stuck at trying to get this to run at startup in a headless environment.
I tried running the string that get the app working through systemd ,local.rc and bashc options but my application crashes 2 seconds after registering on startup.  Keeping in mind the softphone pjsua app has a interactive cli when started in normal enviroment with a screen or when logged in via ssh.
In journalclt i get the fault "cant return to console" and the programme closes.
Do i need to stipulate an output folder and if so how

I would actually like to be able to set the pjisp app to run as a service instead of trying to get app to run with a command in the first place, but for now initializing the app in headless mode is my main goal.

Any advice on how to get around this or propably compile pjsip with my conf will be appreciated.
Should anyone require more specific log files or info please feel free to request.

Jman

Comment: it isn't `pie` .

Answer (score 1):

> In journalclt i get the fault "cant return to console" and the programme closes. Do i need to stipulate an output folder and if so how

That is 100% dependent on how the app itself is coded.  You also say it:

> has a interactive cli when started in normal enviroment

But from the sound of things either it uses an interactive cli, period, or you are not starting it correctly (it may be possible to run it in a background mode via some command line arg).

Stuff run at boot generally does not have access to an interactive console; those are occupied by login prompts.  So one work-around for this would be to enable an auto-login for some user and start the app from `~/.bash_profile` -- just beware that means it will then start for any and logins from that user, including `ssh`, so you might want to create a user dedicated to this purpose who only ever logs in automatically in order to run the app.